# unexpected error "no matching function for call to", expects constructor without parameters

Tags: c++, constructor

This is probably trivial for an experienced C++ programmer, but I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. The following bit of code is reduced to a minimum, so it's rather meaningless, but I just want to understand the compiler error it generates:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   int i;

   MyClass(int some_int);
};

class MyOtherClass
{
public:
   MyClass c;

   MyOtherClass(MyClass mc);
};

MyClass::MyClass(int some_int)
{
   i = some_int;
}

MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(MyClass mc)
{
   c = mc;
}
```

The compiler (MinGW) gives this error:

```
testfile.cpp: In constructor 'MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(MyClass)':
testfile.cpp:22:38: error: no matching function for call to 'MyClass::MyClass()'
```

And sure enough, when I add a constructor without parameters to MyClass, i.e. MyClass::MyClass(), the error is gone. But why is that needed by the constructor of MyOtherClass?

What I find even stranger, is that the following also compiles without errors:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   int i;

   MyClass(int some_int);
};

class MyOtherClass
{
public:
   MyClass c;

   //MyOtherClass(MyClass mc);
   void setMyClass(MyClass mc);
};

MyClass::MyClass(int some_int)
{
   i = some_int;
}

//MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(MyClass mc)
//{
//   c = mc;
//}

void MyOtherClass::setMyClass(MyClass mc)
{
   c = mc;
}
```

So somehow, what is a problem in `MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(MyClass mc)` is perfectly OK in `MyOtherClass::setMyClass(MyClass mc)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this member `MyClass c;` in `MyOtherClass` which becomes default constructed, but `MyClass` does not have a default constructor.

The body of a constructor executes after all members have been constructed. To specify how these become initialized / constructed you need to provide an *initialization list*:

```
MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(MyClass mc)
: c(mc)
{
}
```

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. I was confused by the fact that the line that gave the error also contained the "MyClass mc" argument, but now I see that that had little to do with the error. It is just the fact that it is a constructor, so it tries to construct the class' members before executing the body. I checked by changing the constructor argument to "int i", and I get exactly the same error.